# android grid view multiple choice

Tags: android, gridview, mode, multiple-choice

I am using two-way-gridview library. Maybe someone use it. [The link to library](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview). Does it support multiple choice mode?

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't, maybe because it doesn't extend Android's ListView or GridView. (which it doesn't)